# Determine average of all Node values within a Tree Structure

Tags: java, recursion, tree

Given this interface...

```
public static interface Node 
{
    int getValue();
    List<Node> getChildren();
}
```

Implement the following method to return the average of all node values in the tree.

```
public static double getAverage(Node root) 
{
}
```

I'm having an extremely hard time with this practice problem and have a few questions.

1. I assume this is best completed using recursion, is that correct?
2. Is this possible without a helper method or global variables?
3. Is this possible without having to traverse the tree twice? (Once for node sum, once for node count)

Additionally, if someone could provide some psuedo-code, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Answers to all three of your questions is "yes"; now, can you edit your question and add the code you have already tried?

Comment: So I can create a recursive solution to this problem without adding any helper methods or global variables, and without having to traverse the tree twice?

Comment: @CODe If you mean using only the `getAverage` method that has a signature shown in your question, it is likely that the answer is no. Knowing the average for each subtree is not sufficient: we need to know either the number of nodes in it or a sum.

Comment: @kraskevich indeed, that's what I assumed as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use recursion, but it is possible to solve this problem without it, too. What you need is just a depth-first search. You can implement it iteratively using a stack.
2. Yes, it is possible. A version with a stack does not require any additional methods.
3. Yes, it is possible. You can just compute both of these values during one traversal.

Here is a pseudo code of a non-recursive implementation:

```
valuesSum = 0
nodesCount = 0
stack = new Stack
stack.add(root)
while (!stack.isEmpty())
    Node v = stack.poll()
    nodesCount++
    valuesSum += v.getValue()
    for (child : v.getChildren())
        stack.add(child)
return valuesSum / nodesCount
```

Comment: Is #2 and #3 a yes based on the iterative approach? I assume a version with a stack will not be recursive.

Comment: @CODe #3 is true for any approach. You can return an object that holds a sum and the number of nodes from a helper function if you use a recursive version. #2 is based on iterative version.